# Can I get Raid disk status by using PS?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I have a HP server with Raid 5. Port 0 and 1 are used for data & OS mirroring. The software come with the Raid 5 is Intel Matrix Storage Manager and there is manager console as windows based api to view all the ports, including their status.

Now they are all in Normal status. I am not sure if the OS/Windows has some APIs or .Net classes to access raid ports and get their status? If so, how can I use PS to get the information? Do I have to reference to the dlls provided by the Intel Matrix Storage Manager if not?

Basically, I would like to write a PS script to get read status. In case any of port disk is not normal, a message will be sent out by growl protocol.

Comment: I think what "pstanton" is indicating is that this is more of a sys admin type question, and should be asked at the serverfault.com site.

That being said, I strongly doubt there's a .NET interface to the hardware RAID subsystem.  I think you're best bet (which I've done before on Dell) is to look for/use a command-line interface (good old DOS).  You can call/parse the command-line tool to do what you need with the hardware RAID.

Comment: That's why I post this question to see any one knows if .Net framework provides any classes or api. At the same time, I am going to use Refector to take a look at Intel Matrix Storage Manager dll files to see if there are any .net classes available for use.

Comment: All the dll files I found do not have CLI headers. It seems like that no .Net support for Raid disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HP servers I've used come its own management software in the form of HP System Insight Manager. Insight Manager has both a a web and command-line interface. Details on all H/W health including disks are provided. There is also a backend consolidated SQL database you can stand up. I'm not sure if HP charges extra for this or its part of their server offering. In any case I would recommend looking into SIM.

Comment: going to get one and let you known if I can use its console app working with PS.

Comment: I could not find any tools from HP SIM for my case.

Comment: From past experience, the HP SIM server has a price, yet the agents are free.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $raidvalues = get-wmiobject -class win32_systemdriver | where-object {$_.displayname -like "*mraid*"}
    $rStatus = $raidvalues.Status
```

We use this to check for status of RAID controllers on a Dell PowerEdge.  You may have to find the correct name to replace `*mraid*`. Hope the idea helps.