# How do I monitor the status of a RAID array on an Intel controller from a Windows application?

Tags: windows, intel, raid

I need to check the status of a RAID array on an Intel controller from my Windows application periodically (or be notified about a status change). Specifically, what I need is to find out whether a RAID 5 array is healthy or one of its disks is missing.

I tried parsing output of `raidcfg32` (available from the Intel site, see [this readme](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18324/eng/raidcfg.txt)), but it works only with one of servers my application need to monitor. On other servers `raidcfg32` reports an ‘unsupported hardware’ error. I also tried `CmdTool2`, but it was unable to find the controller altogether.

The only remaining option of RAID array monitoring supplied by Intel is a bunch of GUI applications (Intel Matrix Storage Management Console, Intel Rapid Storage Technology).

The controllers in question are: ESB2, 631xESB/632xESB.

I believe I have read through the few posts here on Stack Overflow that are relevant to my problem, and none of them contains an answer. In an answer to the question ‘[Can I get Raid disk status by using PS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501855/can-i-get-raid-disk-status-by-using-ps)’, for instance, what is suggested actually allows to check if *the controller*, not the array, is healthy (it always is).

What am I looking for is an automated way of accessing the status information (from a .NET application, to be specific). Any option is good, be it via WMI, a .NET or native API, console output parsing or whatever.

I find it confusing that the suggested way of monitoring RAID status is via a GUI application. What approaches are used in enterprise deployments with tens of servers to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking for this also.  I have ICHxxx series controllers and am trying to get a contact at Intel to respond about the existance of a public API, but I'm not optimistic.

Here's what I've come up with for the short-term.  Intel records the RAID events to the Windows Event Log under "IAANTmon".  So you can use System.Diagnostics.EventLog, hooking the EventWrittenEventHandler, then filtering for "IAANTmon".

```
        EventLog eLog = new EventLog("Application");
        eLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWrittenEvent);
        eLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and

```
    public static void OnEntryWrittenEvent(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Entry.Source == "IAANTmon")
        {
         ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this as well, seems like [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) is the best option.
Unfortunately, I didn't find a package that suits my .NET-needs and as it is just something basic, I didn't spend hours on finding a proper solution.

I resorted to starting "smartctl --scan" (part of smartmontools) at the start of my application (Process.Start), harvesting the list of devices from the output and then  periodically starting "smartctl -H *device-name*" for each device.

This will return the SMART overal health test-results of the disk, as long as "PASSED" is returned, you *should* be safe.

While this is far from ideal, it does gives some indication of the health of my raid-disks.

Answer (score 1):

As of 11/16/18, Windows 10, I've run into the same issue, needing to check raid status for intel Raid 10.

EJA's answer mostly worked - I did not get any logs written to source "IAANTmon", however.

At this point I used EJA's answer, but, filter by source "IAStorDataMgrSvc". This is where my raid event logs are written. Furthermore, I checked the messages contain either "Degraded" or "Rebuilding". This will exclude the startup events and pull logs such as "Volume Degraded", "Volume Rebuilding in progress", "Volume Rebuilding complete".

I ended up with something like:

```
private static void OnEntryWrittenEvent(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.Entry.Source == "IAStorDataMgrSvc"
            && (e.Entry.Message.Contains("Degraded")
            || e.Entry.Message.Contains("Rebuilding")))
         {
            // Show status message
         }
      }
```

At startup I also checked logs from previous few days incase a drive was flagged degraded while my program was not running -

```
foreach (var entry in eLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
               .Where(x => x.Source == "IAStorDataMgrSvc" 
                      && (x.TimeWritten - DateTime.Today).TotalDays < 3))
            {
               if (entry.Message.Contains("Degraded")
                  || entry.Message.Contains("Rebuilding"))
               {
                  // Show status message
               }
            }
```

Comment: The "crawling past events" approach is a must, as it **is** a possibility. One should store "last checked" so it covers the whole "not running" interval.